# Tilting osm map tile and other wms layer map tile like qgis map server tile via leaflet?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, leaflet, cartography, 3d

I have set up one osm map tile using mapnik and one wms map server using qgis map server. This both map server are able to render 2d map on web platform . I am now intrested to use these map server with custom looks. For now i am very much intrested to make the tile tilt with certain angle.

Can i make it using leaflet or by using other script?

I want to render my map tile with certain tilt angle like this.

[image]

Comment: You could have a look into http://osm2world.org/

Comment: osm2world uses a Java-based (not JavaScript!) renderer for producing tiles. Although pretty cool it doesn't seem to fit his requirements.

Comment: Thanx for replying AnderJ and scai...

Comment: I just want to tilt the view of my map tile that's it. osm2world.org is really cool but it doesnot fit my requirement

Comment: I guess that `three.js` has this functionality. See a [tutorial](http://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs-release/Tutorial.html) for the qgis2threejs plugin; Some functions of this library may be useful for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Liu at Mapbox wrote a tutorial about tilting a Leaflet map [with CSS transformations](https://blog.mapbox.com/add-a-third-dimension-to-mapbox-js-with-css-5fd5b6addf6c), but found it resulted in awkward interaction and degraded image quality. [Here's a little map I made](http://bl.ocks.org/maptastik/58a19354dc93469e4178) trying to build on Peter's tutorial.

If you're open to other options, [Mapbox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api) might be better suited for a tilted map. It contains [methods for setting both pitch and bearing](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/set-perspective/). They even have an [example using WMS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/wms/).

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers 3 allows tilting of camera angles.